# timer is not getting latest state in react [progress bar in react]

Tags: reactjs, timer, progress-bar, settimeout

Hey I have created this progress bar. The timer inside of useEffect which increases 10% of progress after 1 sec is not getting latest state.

You can simulate that by frquenty clicking the reset button. You can see that timer somehow manages to get an old outdated state.

https://codesandbox.io/s/amazing-rhodes-9mrtqc?file=/src/App.js

Not tried anything yet.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  Please see [Something in my web site or project doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/254428/328193)  Relevant code needs to be included in the question to produce a [mcve] which demonstrates the problem, as well as information about the problem itself and what debugging you have done.  To learn more about this community and how we can help you, please start with the [tour] and read [ask] and its linked resources.

Comment: It seems to be working fine for me. Reset resets the progress to 0.

Comment: Reset frequently, like 10 times in a second. You will see setTimer getting old state. Looks like timer is receiving state when it was started.